# Buddhavamsa Translations?

Tags: pali-canon, reference-request, texts, tipitaka

Do any english translations exist online for the Buddhavamsa ? I cannot find one.

Answer (score 3):

I do not know about any translations but there is this book called [*"The Great Chronicles of Buddhas"*](http://www.bps.lk/olib/mi/mi014.pdf). It's a book only about the different Buddhas and the life of them.

It's a very interesting book with lots of material on them such as daily life, teachings, characteristics etc.

Answer (score 3):

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhavamsa) lists several translations, of which (at least) the last exists as a PDF online, i.e.

> [The great chronicle of Buddhas, Volume One, Part Two](http://www.dhammatalks.net/Books14/Mingun_Sayadaw-The_Great_Chronicle_of_Buddhas_Vol-1_Part-2.pdf) (PDF) (1st ed.).

Answer (score 2):

[Buddhavamsa](http://dhammadownload.com/File-Library/MinGunSayadawGyi/MinGunSayadawGyi-TGC-V1P2.pdf) by most venerable [Mingun Sayadaw Bhaddanta Vicittasarabhivamsa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mingun_Sayadaw).
He is best known for his memory skills and his role in the [Sixth Buddhist Council](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sixth_Buddhist_council). The late Ven. Mahasi Sayadaw was appointed to ask the required questions about the Dhamma to the Ven. Bhadanta Vicittasarabhivamsa, who answered them.